# Why doesn't Object.setProtoypeOf work on functions?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have the below code:

```
"use strict";

function Student() {}

Student.prototype.sayName = function () {
  console.log(this.name);
};

function EighthGrader(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.grade = 8;
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(EighthGrader, Student.prototype);
const carl = new EighthGrader("carl");

carl.sayName(); // Uncaught TypeError: carl.sayName is not a function
```

why doesn't `Object.setPrototypeOf` work on function if all all function in JavaScript are also objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setPrototypeOf` method works just fine on functions, you can now do `EighthGrader.sayName()` (which will say the `EightGrader` [function's `.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)) and can no longer do `EighthGrader.call()` which was previously inherited from `Function.prototype`.

It's just that you didn't *want* to use it on the function, but rather on the prototype object that `carl` inherits from. To do that, you'll have to use

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(EighthGrader.prototype, Student.prototype);
```

The prototype chain of `carl` is

```
carl -> EighthGrader.prototype -> …
```

not

```
carl -> EightGrader -> …
```

Comment: `EighthGrader.sayName()` works fine as well. Using a function like a constructor isn't the same as cloning the function.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Is this a request for clarification or just meant as additional info for the OP?

Comment: Additional info, but I believe that you understand it better than I do. Your prototype chain explains it all.